# Custom Product export in Magento 1

Tags: product, magento-1.7, csv, export

I want to Product export. But I need Only data which I need.

For example, I need not "gift_message_available" attribute value. So Please tell me what I should

I have created the profile. but When I run that profile, the CSV file downloaded in var folder. So in that case, I need to FTP details.

but I want to download directly my System.

Comment: you want to manually export product like script?

Comment: yes, I want to create a cutom module for that. So I can export product with my selected attribute.

Answer (score 1):

1. On the Admin menu, select `System > Import/Export > Export`.
2. In the `Export Settings` section, do the following:

   a. Set Entity Type to `Products`
   b. Accept the default Export File Format of “`CSV`.”
3. In the `Entity Attributes` section, you can include or exclude data to be exported according to the entity attribute values.

   -> To include records with specific attribute values, set the required values of the attributes in the Filter column.

   -> To omit an attribute from the export, select the Skip checkbox at the beginning of the row.
4. Scroll down and click the Continue button in the lower-right corner of the page. Look for the download prompt in the lower-right corner of your browser.

**The CSV file that is generated can be edited and imported back into your store. Or, it can be used for mailing or other applications.**

Comment: this solution is not to skip some attribute which is default Magento.
Like use_config_min_qty,is_qty_decimal,backorders,use_config_backorders min_sale_qty,use_config_min_sale_qty